# How to get the location of a purchased phone number in Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm working on a project using the Twilio API. I've noticed that the availablePhoneNumbers collection sends us, along with the available numbers, their geo-location, rate center, a lot of very useful information about the number I'm about to purchase.

After purchasing the number, I realised the incomingPhoneNumbers collection doesn't have any such thing as phone location, ISO country, and so on!

Is there a way to retrieve this information for numbers already purchased, or should I save it for every number I get from availablePhoneNumbers in case I'll buy it later?

Also, I guess this is another question, there doesn't seem to be a way to know via API if a number is enabled to send/receive calls/SMS internationally. I need to automate the purchasing of numbers via API, and while their frontend allows me to see if a number has certain restrictions before buying it, I can't find an API method to do so. The API simply says if a number is enabled to send or receive SMS for example, but it doesn't state if it can send/receive them to/from numbers out of its own country.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you want to use all the data about a phone number that is returned from the [Available Phone Numbers resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/available-phone-numbers) then you will want to cache it somewhere it until you buy the number. You can get the ISO country code of a number if you use the [Lookups API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/lookups). Location for phone numbers is only supported for US and Canada.

As for your other question, I'm afraid that is not currently part of the API, however I inquired within Twilio and it is an improvement that we are looking into, so look out for it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Here in 2022, still doesn't look like we have a good way of tackling this.

[The current `IncomingPhoneNumber` resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource) doesn't seem to have any regional information (eg, city, state), though a new (and generally unavailable ) [Active Numbers API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/global-catalog/api/active-numbers) has solid information under `items.*.geography`...just a bummer that it's in a private dev preview.

Seems like this info should be accessible, as Twilio's own console shows city/state for each of your active numbers on [the index page](https://console.twilio.com/us1/develop/phone-numbers/manage/active?frameUrl=%2Fconsole%2Fphone-numbers%2Fincoming%3Fx-target-region%3Dus1).

Comment: I've simpy given up on Twilio. Their API improved but it's still not enough to create a meaningful service with it! Thanks for your 2022 contribution!